# undefined variable $conx in class

Tags: php, class, oop, include

I was wondering if you can explain why PHP acts this way when including files in __construct methods.

```
class sitePosting{

private $conx;

public function __construct() {
    include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/db_conx.php");
    $this->conx = $conx;
}
```

It seems that if I call another class which has this file included in its __construct, I get an undefined variable error when trying to use $conx in the first class, but from what I understand isn't __construct run when the object is first built?

**What's weirder, if I change...**

`include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/db_conx.php");`

**TO**

`include("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/db_conx.php");`

This fixes the problem entirely, but I have no idea why

Any insight into why this occurs is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is `$conx` declare in constructor  ?

Comment: It's declared inside the db_conx.php as a mysqli object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the names says: include_once includes the file only once. If You have included it earlier it won't be included again. Also, classes and functions don't see the global scoped variables unlike JavaScript for example. That's why the $conx variable is unreachable from within You sitePosting class.

It would be better if You placed $conx as class argument like this:

```
public function __construct($conx) {
    $this->conx = $conx;
}
```

It's called Dependency Injection and is definitely a good practice to use. Makes Your code much cleaner and understendable.